# How to increase navigator font size in XCode?

Tags: xcode14.3

I use 32" monitor with my macbook.

I know, Xcode has 'Navigator Size' option (Small-Medium-Large-System).

But these options not enough for me. I need another solution.

I don't want to change the screen resolution.

Thanks for help.